# How can I parse a csv that contains JSON with logstash

Tags: json, csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I have an elk stack where I would like to parse a csv where one field contains json but I run into a logstash error. So I need to know how I can parse the json field in the csv into elasticssearch.

> 10:54:20.220 [[main]>worker1] WARN  logstash.filters.csv - Error
>   parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"431|2017-01-26
>   10:08:57|example@example.com|firstName|lastName|GBP|GB|2015-06-14
>   07:16:39|43.88|2017-01-24
>   13:45:28|f|{\"18272\":{\"19208\":\"1\",\"19210\":\"1\"},\"18218\":{\"19099\":\"1\"},\"18783\":{\"19249\":\"2\"}}|5|GBP",
>   :exception=>#}

An example row in the csv looks like this, as you can see it is delimiter separated.

> 431|2017-01-26
>   10:08:57|example@example.com|firstName|lastName|GBP|GB|2015-06-14
>   07:16:39|43.88|2017-01-24
>   13:45:28|f|{\"18272\":{\"19208\":\"1\",\"19210\":\"1\"},\"18218\":{\"19099\":\"1\"},\"18783\":{\"19249\":\"2\"}}|5|GBP

My config is as follows.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/etc/logstash/files/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => "|"
      columns => ['userId', 'profileUpdated', 'email', 'lastName', 'firstName', 'userCurrency', 'billingCountry', 'registeredDate', 'cartValue', 'cartUpdated', 'kitInCart', 'cart' 'itemsInCart' ,'cartCurrency']
  }
  json {
    source => 'cart'
  }
  date {
    match => [ "registeredDate", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
     index => "users"
  }
}
```

As you can see above my cart field is the json one.

Comment: It seems you're missing a field between `cart` and `currency` for the last but one value `20`

Comment: I've update to reflect some changes I've just made, I've tested it by dropping the cart from the csv and changing the config and it imports no problem it just seems to be when I add the cart into the csv.

Comment: What happens if you also add `target => "cart"` to your `json` filter?

Comment: Can you also show the logstash error you're getting?

Comment: I've updated the question to include a full line and the full error that it generates. I get the same error even with target added to the config.

Comment: It seems to be the message field it's grumbling at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to my csv filterconfig file and it worked.

> quote_char => "'"

Comment: Glad you figured it out